What does `f, ax = plt.subplots(...)` do?
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)

What does the f, ax do?
I can roughly understand that ax = ax means to assign the graph. But what does f do?

Please see the "Returns" section under pyplot.subplots.

See also Returning a tuple
